# Polymer core-scaffold scroll to top

Tags: polymer

After some search I found that [I could scroll `core-header-panel` by `scroller` property](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25150182/2407522), but I cannot apply the same thing to `core-scaffold`.

Is there any way to scroll core-scaffold to the top ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Winchestro answer,

I could solve it by defining a `scroller` property for my `custom-core-scaffold` and make it return  the `core-header-panel` scroller.

```
get scroller() {
  return this.$.headerPanel.scroller;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A core-scaffold element is just a collection of a bunch of other core elements with a bit of commonly used functionality. If the documentation doesn't answer your question one tip is to just look inside the source of the element.

That's for example the content of the core-scaffold.

```
<div vertical layout drawer>

  <content select="[navigation], nav"></content>

</div>

<core-header-panel id="headerPanel" main mode="{{mode}}">

  <core-toolbar>
    <core-icon-button id="menuButton" icon="menu" on-tap="{{togglePanel}}"></core-icon-button>
    <content select="[tool]"></content>
  </core-toolbar>

  <content select="*"></content>

</core-header-panel>
```

The .$ property will contain a path to any element by its id. So `$.yourScaffoldID.$.headerPanel` is a path you can use to access it through javascript or data-binding.